# How to use PushMeBaby sample to send Apple Push Notifications?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use PushMeBaby sample APN Server application to send push notifications to my device. I have adhoc distribution application. For my application ID I have created both ssl certificates for development and production. It seems to be not sending push notifications from PushMeBaby application, I have alread installed Push SSL certificates to the tool chain.. still it seems to be not working..

```
2010-02-01 07:20:49.578 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] MakeServerConnection(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:49.613 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SSLNewContext(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:49.614 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SSLSetIOFuncs(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:49.614 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SSLSetConnection(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:49.615 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SSLSetPeerDomainName(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:49.631 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SecKeychainOpen(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:49.648 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SecCertificateCreateFromData(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:49.655 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:49.656 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SSLSetCertificate(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:52.353 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SSLHandshake(): 0
2010-02-01 07:20:57.954 PushMeBaby[7193:a0f] SSLWrite(): 0 144
```

Above is the log of PusheBaby xcode application.

Comment: Need more information to help, like the relevant code from your application, etc.

Comment: Please post answer if you solved above problem. Facing same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK - Figured this out.

The device token I was passing in (which I got from UrbanAirship) had no spaces. I used the device token from the console from the iPhone app per this great tutorial (http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services) which has spaces between every 8 chars in the string. That did the trick.

The device token should look like this - 38c866dd bb323b39 ffa73487 5e157ee5 a85e0b7c e90d56e9 fe145bcc 6c2c594b

Later - when you look at the NSLog from PushMeBaby - you will see the "processed" count in the SSLWrite call increased by 1 (mine went from 104 to 105) 
e.g. 2011-04-28 11:21:41.543 PushMeBaby[49218:903] SSLWrite(): 0 105

Hope this helps somebody else who struggled like me for days...

Comment: **Thanks for the answer mate.** I switched to some java alternative in server side finally. Might this will help some other guy.

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/jlott1/PushMeBaby-OneMoreTime) instead of `Pushmebaby`, which don't need to add space manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add my two cents here since this got me too.  If you realized that the device token should have had spaces, then to never have this problem again replace this section of code:

```
    // Validate input.
    if(self.deviceToken == nil || self.payload == nil) {
        return;
    }
```

with this:

```
    // Validate input.
    if(self.deviceToken == nil || self.payload == nil) {
        return;
    }
    else if(![self.deviceToken rangeOfString:@" "].length)
    {
        //put in spaces in device token
        NSMutableString* tempString =  [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.deviceToken];
        int offset = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tempString.length; i++)
        {
            if(i%8 == 0 && i != 0 && i+offset < tempString.length-1)
            {
                //NSLog(@"i = %d + offset[%d] = %d", i, offset, i+offset);
                [tempString insertString:@" " atIndex:i+offset];
                offset++;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@" device token string after adding spaces = '%@'", tempString);
        self.deviceToken = tempString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes for Push me baby the device token should be

```
45f62964 06523099 b66017f7 0eb3ea7d 14140c11 af6f14a0 c24145d1 90005763

not
<45f62964 06523099 b66017f7 0eb3ea7d 14140c11 af6f14a0 c24145d1 90005763>
or
45f6296406523099b66017f70eb3ea7d14140c11af6f14a0c24145d190005f9c
```

if you include the <> it goes into an infinite loop in an NSScanner

Though officially the device token should include <> and spaces as thats what you get when you RegisterDevice
if you use it in other apps such as APN TESTER on MAC APP STORE

```
<45f62964 06523099 b66017f7 0eb3ea7d 14140c11 af6f14a0 c24145d1 90005763>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this before

```
// Convert string into device token data.
```

to `-(IBAction)push:(id)sender;` in `ApplicationDelegate.h`.

```
if (![self.deviceToken rangeOfString:@" "].length) {
    NSMutableString *string = [self.deviceToken mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 8; i < string.length; i+=8) {
        [string insertString:@" " atIndex:i];
    }
    self.deviceToken = string;
}
```

And now you it is supported the "spaceless" format.